# 'cannot find artifact' on hardhat deploy

Tags: javascript, hardhat

Following workshop of https://www.twitch.tv/videos/1218449997

GitHub repo: https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/battle-game

On the command `npx hardhat deploy` getting an error:

```
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing /home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/deploy/01_deploy_champion_quest_token.js:
Error: cannot find artifact "ChampionQuestToken"
    at getArtifact (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:213:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:526:9)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
    at getArtifactFromOptions (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:486:18)
    at getLinkedArtifact (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:496:38)
    at _deploy (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:517:54)
    at _deployOne (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:910:16)
    at Object.deployMocks [as func] (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/deploy/01_deploy_champion_quest_token.js:12:30)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1220:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:526:9)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1050:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:405:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:217:14)
    at Environment.run (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:129:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/zage/code/HackChainLink/ChampionQuest/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:551:32)
```

`01_deploy_champion_quest_token.js` code is here:

```
    /* eslint-disable node/no-unpublished-import */
    // eslint-disable-next-line node/no-missing-import
    
    const hre = require("hardhat")
    
    const deployMocks = async function (hre) {
        const { deployments, getNamedAccounts, getChainId } = hre
        const { deploy, log, get } = deployments
        const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
        const chainId = await getChainId()
        const ufoToken = await get("MockUFO")
        const championQuestToken = await deploy("ChampionQuestToken", {
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [ufoToken.address],
        })
    }
    module.exports = deployMocks
    deployMocks.tags = ["all", "token"]
```

Code cloned from github repo.

Tried to delete `cache` and `artifacts` folders - did't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, but it seems really weird

In my case I had one more contract `ChampionQuest.sol` which was almost empty, when I had that problem.
Once I copy `ChampionQuest.sol` from github repo everything went fine.

However I don't understand why deploy scripts would complain on `cannot find artifact "ChampionQuestToken"`.

Cause changes was made in another contract `ChampionQuest.sol` which is not used inside of 01_deploy_champion_quest_token.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).